# Table Storage query CopyPipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need configure Azure Data Factory CopyPipeline source query for copying data from Storage Table by PartitionKey, and I can not find how I can do it ...

Which language is used for querying here? I found something about `FetchXML`, but it is totally unknown to me. Is there some other variant?

For example (in T-SQL) - I need simply something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [StorageTableName] WHERE PartitionKey = [MyPartKey]
```

Thanks for the help...

Edit:
I found this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-table-connector#azure-table-copy-activity-type-properties) and try query example:

"azureTableSourceQuery": "$$Text.Format('PartitionKey ge \'{0:yyyyMMddHH00_0000}\' and PartitionKey le \'{0:yyyyMMddHH00_9999}\'', SliceStart)"

, but I got just error:

A storage operation failed with the following error 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'.. Activity ID: ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table storage query code is like this:

```
1. (PartitionKey eq 'Sales') and (RowKey eq 'Smith')
2. PartitionKey eq '1' and RowKey ge '2' 
3. PartitionKey eq 'Sales' and LastName eq 'Smith'
```

Replace the '0' and '1' with your PartitionKey and RowKey value.

[image]

You can reference this document [How your choice of PartitionKey and RowKey impacts query performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query#how-your-choice-of-partitionkey-and-rowkey-impacts-query-performance).

Hope this helps.